# RxJava - how to achieve a delayed timeout

Tags: rx-java

a question to the more (than me) RxJava skilled ones.

I'm subscribed to a PublishSubject which is supposed to emit a result message within 60sec + 5sec tolerance. If I don't receive it in time, it's assumed that there's a problem on the senders side and I need to abort.

Usually I would subscribe to it like this:

```
subject
.timeout(65, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.subscribe(
// onNext
    { msg -> handleSuccess(msg)},
//onError
    { t-> handleError(t) }
)
```

The thing is, the subject might also send update messages during this 60 seconds. So my OnNext would look like:

```
{ msg -> when (msg){
      is ResultMessage -> handleSuccess(msg)
      is UpdateMessage -> handleUpdate(msg)    
    }
}
```

You see my problem, receiving an UpdateMessage would reset my timeout. The ideal way to me would be, if I could set a timeout of 5sec, but with an initial delay of 60seconds before it's armed.

I know, I could set an extra plain timer outside of the subscription, but I hope there's a more elegant reactive solution to that.

Comment: so you want to wait for 65sec only for a specific type of message not the `UpdateMessage` one ?

Comment: The ResultMessage must be received within the 65 seconds, otherwise a timeout should trigger. The UpdateMessages are optional, but must be processed, if received

Comment: `UpdateMessages` would not reset the timeout of `ResultMessage` ?

Comment: It would, The Subject sends out objects of type "Message", which can be either UpdateMessage or ResultMessage. The timeout resets with every received emission.
I am aware I could subscribe twice on the subect, checking for either message type in the respective subscriptions and only have the one waiting for the Result working with a timeout. I'm just looking for a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to establish two different subscriptions and filter:

```
subject
    .filter( /*is update*/ )
    .subscribe( /*...*/ );

subject
    .filter( /*is result*/ )
    .timeout( 65, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
    .subscribe( /*...*/ );
```

Comment: Thx, my own solution got along with one subscription, but also using a filter

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up with, is to pull the handling of UpdateMessages one step further in doOnNext and filter the emitted messages to ResultMessage. This way, the timeout only affects the ResultMessage emissions.

```
        subject
            .doOnNext{msg ->
                    if (msg is UpdateMessage)
                        handleUpdate(msg)
            }
            .filter{ msg -> msg is ResultMessage }
            .timeout(65, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(
                    // onNext
                    { msg -> handleSuccess(msg)},
                    //onError
                    { t-> handleError(t) }
            )
```